# Android studio RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every time I run the app on emulator or phone it keeps stopping and t

My logcat looks like this

```
04-07 07:19:27.348 5670-5670/com.example.anandsagar.uapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main     Process: com.example.anandsagar.uapp, PID: 5670     
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo {com.example.anandsagar.uapp/com.example.anandsagar.uapp.MainActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton        
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)        

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
```

what should i do

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your XML has a button like

That package is not correct..

Check class and package of that button